# python output directory not getting created

Tags: python, directory

I want to run a python script which deletes the output directory if it exists, and then creates it. If it does not exist, it simply creates it. The code is below:

```
if os.path.exists(out_dir):  
    shutil.rmtree(out_dir)  
    os.makedirs(out_dir)  
else:  
    os.makedirs(out_dir)
```

However, if the output directory already exists when I run this code, it gives an error:

> WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists:

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use `os.path.isdir()` instead?
`os.path.exists()` might be True if there's a file in the directory that has the same name as the folder

Answer (score 1):

In the if condition body, it might be the case that shutil.rmtree(out_dir) failed to delete your existing folder and in the next line you are trying to create a new directory using os.makedirs(out_dir).

Answer (score 1):

rmtree should work.

Try this instead

os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, name))

Note that rmtree will fail if there are read-only files.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    os.makedirs(out_dir)
except OSError:
    shutil.rmtree(out_dir)
    os.makedirs(out_dir)
```

makedirs Raises an error exception if the leaf directory already exists or cannot be created.